# What is the simplest way to add multi language support to a simple mobile app?

Tags: mobile, multilingual, language-translation, appery.io

I am working on a simple mobile online shop app and need to add internationalization to it.
For example, the products' descriptions need to be presented in, at least three languages. Also, the user should be able to select the needed language.
Want to use Appery as a tool since the app should work for both iOS and Android.

Comment: Did you mean you want to build a cross-platform mobile app using framework like Flutter, etc ?

Answer (score 3):

1. Create the TypeScript code with the type Angular i18n language and the following content

> ```
> {
>     "Card_Title": "Hello!",
>     "Card_Content": {
>         "spec_value_1": "This is a multilingual app",
>         "spec_value_2": "Made by:"    
>     }
> }
> ```

2. Add the ngx-translate library (see this link on how to add it https://docs.appery.io/docs/ionic-5-internationalization-sample-app)
3. Now you can use the library ngx-translate in your project

More information you can find here: https://docs.appery.io/docs/ionic-5-property-internationalization